# Multiple CBCentralManager instances?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Are multiple `CBCentralManager` instances supported? If so, in which version of iOS did they begin to be supported?

I've found [multiple](http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2013/Jan/msg00092.html) [emails](http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2013/May/msg00013.html) on the Apple mailing lists stating that they are not. However, this is not enforced with exceptions or by having a theoretical `+sharedCentralManager`. One states that the documentation says that they are not supported. However, that is no longer mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html), and the current header file comment (iOS 8.3 SDK) is:

```
/*!
 *  @class CBCentralManager
 *
 *  @discussion Entry point to the central role. Commands should only be issued when its state is <code>CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn</code>.
 *
 */
```

I don't expect `CBPeripheral` instances to be portable between `CBCentralManager` instances (that's not what this question is about), I'd just expect to have multiple "windows" into the Bluetooth stack (without any irregular behavior).

Comment: It would be better to have a single CBCentralManager instance and design your app around that. Why do you need multiple?

Comment: I don't see how that's "better" - especially since that's essentially forcing a singleton, which I generally consider poor design. Either it works or it doesn't. If it doesn't work, fair enough, but this appears to be completely undocumented (and it was previous documented, thus the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 8.3, it appears that creating a second `CBCentralManager` instance will cause the second instance to report its state as `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported` (`2`). Therefore, multiple instances of `CBCentralManager` are not supported.

Comment: I do not observe the same behavior. I'm running 8.3 and have multiple managers, all in the powered on state.

Comment: @Kevin Hi, as you said multiple managers are supported in iOS 8.3, but can they all connect to the same peripheral?

Comment: Seems that someone got an answer from Apple support that is in contradiction with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221338/are-multiple-instances-of-cbcentralmanager-objects-supported